# NodeMCU ESP32 returning [E][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1230] hostByName(): DNS Failed for example.com

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I am trying to make an HTTP request over WiFi from an ESP32, but upon connecting to the host, this error is displayed in serial console

```
[ 21036][E][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1230] hostByName(): DNS Failed for httpbin.org
```

The code is as follows (PlatformIO C++ using the Arduino framework)

```c
const char *ssid = "Nebula's iPhone";
const char *password = "password";
const char *host = "httpbin.org";

...

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (!WiFi.isConnected()) {
    delay(100);
  }
  WiFi.config(WiFi.localIP(), WiFi.gatewayIP(), WiFi.subnetMask(),
              IPAddress(1, 1, 1, 1), IPAddress(8, 8, 8, 8));
}

...

void makeRequest() {
  httpsClient.connect(host, 443); // Fails here
}
```

Comment: Have you try the [WiFiClientStaticIP](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WiFiClientStaticIP/WiFiClientStaticIP.ino) example? The `WiFi.config()` needs to be setup before calling `WiFi.begin()`.